# Yii & Opencart Integration : How to create anything new in opencart using Yii Framework?

Tags: yii, frameworks, opencart

`Opencart` is a very famous Cart Framework, providing lots of features, rewriting them is not worthy.

But for some internal new feature development If i want to use `Yii` Framework then from where i should start and how to integrate `Yii` on `opencart`.

Please describe the process to follow.

Comment: you can't integrate these two frameworks together, `OC` has it's own structure (booting, controllers, models, routing ...) and so is `Yii`, for some internal new feature development you should follow [OC rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru)

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose either one OpenCart or Yii, if you choose OpenCart you can import some library function from Yii inside this folder `system/library` and you can call using opencart prebuild function.

Other than that is not a good idea to recreate again using Yii since OpenCart also is using MVC structure.